# Earthquake - does it affect units in docks?

Tags: the-business-game

So in a game of 'Mine a Million' aka 'The Business Game' the production card came up with Earthquake at Newport. The card's description officially says:

> All Warehouse stocks belonging to all players are lost

So the question is, if stock is kept inside a barge at the barge dock (or a ship in the ship berth) does that make it safe from the earthquake as technically the goods aren't in the warehouse?

Comment: @Rainbolt thanks for creating a tag for me :) I actually wonder if there should be a rule-clarification tag too? This isn't really "house-rules" per se but its the only tag I could find

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe there should be a tag for rules, but I won't create it because it seems too broad. Not many people are experts on all board and card games. The folks using the site a few years ago had [this discussion](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/818/6692).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the cards in my version of *Mine a Million* are open to a bit of interpretation, but I think this one is fairly clear.

- This card specifically mentions "warehouse stocks". It does not mention barges or ships.
- Similar cards for losses at the pithead specify "on the ground (not in lorry/barge)" and/or "in lorry/barge" *(wording not exact, I couldn't quickly find the wording online and I'm not at home to check)*.

On the basis that the cards make it very clear when stocks in a barge at the pithead *are* at risk, I suggest the interpretation that **stocks in a barge or ship are safe against earthquakes.**

In fact, just last night when that card was showing, I put all my stocks (from both my players) in a ship and left my wife's stocks (from both her players) sitting in the warehouse. Unfortunately she managed to sell them before anyone rolled a 1 or 6 :(

Comment: That's a good thought process - and one which hopefully I can justify to the other players when they say "You can't do that!" :)